# Reseller hosting for small organization with one website per project?

Tags: web-hosting, reseller

## Context

I am helping a small non-profit organization to administrate a couple of websites. The organization has 5 sub-projects, which have their own web hosting and DNS subscription (with different providers).

Example:

- *project1* has the domain name `project1.com` and is hosted by *Company1*
- *project2* has the domain name `project2.eu` and is hosted by *Company2*
- ...

## The question

I would like to merge all the hosting subscriptions in one, so we only deal with one hosting company and subscription. A possible way to do it is having a reseller subscription where I can create sub-accounts for each project.

However, I have never done this before so it could be possible that I am missing something. **Is this a correct solution to the problem? Is there anything else I should be aware of when choosing for a reseller subscription?**

Comment: Many hosting accounts will let you host multiple domains under a single account.   Would you consider a single account with a single user name and password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach will work. Get a small reseller account (~10 domains) with a control panel of your preference (cPanel being the most popular) and transfer project1 and project2 there.

However, in my opinion, a small VPS or a Cloud server (with cPanel license) would be optimal. This requires some knowledge of Linux but gives you a lot more control as an admin.

PS: Most webhosts will help new clients migrate over their domains. Good luck!

Comment: I second this answer! You do not need a reseller account. Using a control panel and a hosting account that allows multiple domains is perfectly fine. The only caveat is if you need SSL/certificates for anything. Then you might need a bit more than just an account but most of this can be had ala carte' if not all. And yes. Look for a webhost that will help walk you through a bunch of set-up stuff. I was a webhost years ago and would do all of your set-up and deploy your site for you simply because we were big ole' meanies!!

Comment: I have never worked with a VPS before. How is the learning curve compared to a reseller account? Would it be possible to deploy a new website with a few clicks (or ssh commands)?

Comment: Yes, you can deploy a domain with few clicks using most control panels. As for learning curve, the advantage of going with well known and supported control panel is that you have a lot of documentation.